Is there any entrypoint that receives the document changes in Onlyoffice?
How get the changes text  in Onlyoffice? Now document storage service  could receive the callback from onlyofficeserver which contains diff.zip when a document is saved.
But there is encrypted data in diff.zip, I  could not realize what changed.
The requirement is, receive document changes and store them as a record outside of Onlyoffice.

I tried to fix the English but the second sentence is too cryptic for me to try to make any sense of. What do you mean by "store application"? (I'm not familiar with Onlyoffice so this could simply be a matter of unfamiliar terminology.)

Unfortunately, there is no way to parse the diff.zip file to obtain the differences in a readable format.
If you need to display the differences between two versions, you need to implement the version history. This will allow all changes to be displayed in the history panel.
You can use the compare documents option running in the background.
